# how can I implement subscribe in html template in angular7

Tags: angular7

`getEmployee()` is a method in my service page and now I want employee list without subscribe `showEmployee()` method in my component using HTML template.

```
 showEmployee(){
        this.employeeModel= this._empService.getEmployee();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
employeeModel : Observable<any>
```

or If It as List

```
employeeModel : Observable<any[]>=[];


showEmployee(){
        this.employeeModel= this._empService.getEmployee();
  }
```

***In Html  if You have List Type Then***

```
 <div *ngFor="let data as employeeModel | async">

    .... code for show data Like  {{data.property Name }}

    </div>
```

***If Its an Object***

```
<div> {{employeeModel | async}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the pipe in the html element:

```
<p *ngFor="let data as employeeModel | async">
    <span> {{data.empName}}</span>
</p>
```